# Redirect domain and page ID

Tags: regex, url, redirect

I would like to redirect domain and product ID using 2 variable the first one for domain and second one for page id like:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$/4640-(.*)$ https://www.new-domain.com/$1/5291-$2 [R=301,L]
```

Example from:

```
https://www.old-domain.com/folder_A/4640-product_name.html
```

to

```
https://www.new-domain.com/folder_A/5291-product_name.html
```

Comment: your question is too vague, can you please give more details on what exactly you want

Comment: are you using IIS url rewrite or .htaccess?

Comment: You have two end of string anchors  in the regex. Use one or none - `^/(.*)/4640-(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

Regex for `RewriteRule` shouldn't start with `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$/4640-(.*)$ https://www.new-domain.com/$1/5291-$2 [R=301,L]
```

And [**@Wiktor Stribiżew**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) is right:

> You have two end of string anchors in the regex. Use one or none - `^/(.*)/4640-(.*)`

Fix it with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/4640-(.*)$ https://www.new-domain.com/$1/5291-$2 [R=301,L]
```